# Is the number 101 being used as adjective?

Tags: phrase-usage

In phrases like:

1 "Wine 101"

2 "Microsoft Excel 101"

according to that source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(number)

the number 101 refer to introductory level of learning or a collection of introductory materials to a topic

if 101 is being used as adjective, shouldn't be come before the noun? like:

101 Wine

or

101 Microsoft Excel

Comment: The number is part of the name., like Chanel No 5.  Even if it were not, there is no absolute requirement in English to place adjectives ahead of the the nouns they modify. **A man, stout, red-faced and out of breath, hammered on our door.**

Comment: In AmE, when referring to a basic level of knowledge we say: the area (history) followed by 101. 101= a course in x. As a title, the 101 comes second, the subject area first: English Grammar 101.

Comment: I don't think "part of speech" labels such as "adjective, noun,..."  are particularly useful when trying to understand usages like *Wearing a lab coat and glasses is Lab Safety **101**.* Just file them under ***idiomatic usages*** and don't try to "deconstruct" them any further.

Comment: [Sometimes  adjectives come *after* a noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#In_modern_English)

Answer (score 22):

The "101" here is part of a fixed formula meaning "an introductory or basic course in some topic". Most usages would use it as a title, not part of a sentence, so the part of speech is unclear.

This usage of "101" comes from a naming scheme used in many US universities for naming classes:

- The subject the course belongs to
- A first digit representing the academic level, where "1" is the simplest / introductory level
- Additional digits to distinguish multiple courses at a similar level

Because US degree programs generally allow students to take a wide variety of courses, particularly in their first year, there are many courses which are an introduction to a particular area of study. These are assigned names like "Biology 101", or "Artificial Intelligence 101".

That has led to a popular usage (particularly in the US) of the template "Topic 101" as a short-hand way to say that something is a beginner's introduction of some sort.

Similar postfix labels are often used in product names, such as "Peugeot 208", "Chanel Number 5", or "Pimm's Number 6".

Comment: What you say is true. However, Wine 101 is a title, like a course: Introduction to European History (101). But we could also say; I took a 101 course in European history.

Comment: @Lambie I don't recall hearing it that way, but as a British English speaker, my knowledge of this is mostly second-hand, so you may well be right.

Comment: This naming scheme is less common than you might expect. My college used four-digit numbers, and while the first digit for intro-level courses was often a 1, the subsequent digits were assigned in a more or less arbitrary way by the registrar. To my understanding, course numbers are often unique across the entire college or university, not just within a given subject or department (imagine: would *you* want to have to deal with lots of classes with conflicting numbers, if you were managing class registrations?), so actual "[subject] 101" classes are probably rather unusual.

Comment: @Kevin I have encountered 4-digit class numbers frequently enough, but in the US I've never personally seen or heard of number-only class identifiers. Instead, it's almost always "XXXX NNN(N)", such as "ENGL 101" or "MATH 4321".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: You're right, that does appear to be what my college actually does (it's been a few years). *However*, they have no standard number reserved for "this is the intro course." So for example, Intro to Biology is BIOL 1010, Computer Science I is CSCI 1100, and some subjects start in the 2000's or higher (because they don't really offer a full four-year course in those subjects, just a bunch of secondary electives etc.).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- **MIT** traditionally used only numbers _in combination_; they use 'course' to mean the subject _area_ aka department (2 is Mechanical Engineering) and 'subject' to mean a specific topic taught over one term (2.001 is Mechanics and Materials I). But in recent years some letters have crept in. See http://student.mit.edu/catalog/search.cgi?search=introduction&style=verbatim for some examples. Similarly most schools have numbered rooms in named buildings, but MIT mostly numbers the buildings, so 9-101 is room 101 in building 9.

Comment: I've looked at several dictionary definitions and they all say that 101 is an adjective. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/101 and https://www.dictionary.com/browse/101 and https://www.thefreedictionary.com/101 and https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/101 How do explain this?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Lexicographers like to classify things, and adjective is the category that fits closest. But actual users of the language don't go around thinking "I'm going to use the adjective 101 here", they just follow the template, which is why I say it's not a "natural" adjective.

Comment: I agree that native speakers don't care much for parts of speech, and never stop to think if a word they are saying is a noun, verb, preposition etc. But it is the OP who wants to know its classification, and calling 101 "a label" is skirting the issue. The expression "101" modifies the noun, and  like many adjectives "101" can be modified by adverbs such as *very*, *hardly*, and *basically*.  That's not to say your answer is not good, it is and it's more useful to understand the meaning of 101 but it also describes a *thing* be it a course, a class or the title of a book.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think there's a certain amount of reverse engineering happening here - like the verb "to lase" being invented from the acronym "LASER". You can re-analyse "101" as an adjective and say "it is very 101", or (as suggested elsewhere on this page) re-analyse as a noun and say "it is the 101 of X". Most usages though do neither, they just use it as an invariant form, which isn't produced by any normal rules of grammar, because it comes from an artificial coding system.

Comment: (1) I doubt you'd find a course called "AI 101"; more likely, a course like COMP 306 would be entitled "Intro to Artificial Intelligence (and COMP 406 might be "Adv Topics in AI"), because AI is not its own dept, and it's not usually an elementary class. (2) As for 3- vs. 4-digit course codes, the university where I teach recently made a switch from 3 digits to 4 – perhaps to allow more codes for more courses? Still, I think the "101" nomenclature will be around for a long time, So indeed my wife might say, "You can't tell the difference between a poodle and barbet? That's Dog Breeding 101!"

Answer (score 14):

In this case, “101” is not an adjective but part of a proper noun (aka name). This is no different from the numbers in “Terminator 2”, “Chapter 5” or “Henry VIII”.

“101” in particular references the convention of US colleges to name courses by their department and course number within that department. So, “Math 101” would be course number 101 in the Math department. Within that convention, the first digit of the number signifies the year number of the typical student, and the following two digits are usually assigned sequentially as courses are created. The first course created for first-year students in every department is naturally an introductory course, so this led to “*Subject* 101” being applied outside a college context, and that in turn became so common that now even people who’ve never attended college will recognize it.

Also, while it doesn’t apply here, do note that adjectives *can* come after nouns; it’s not as common today as it was centuries ago, but it’s sometimes still done for literary or poetic effect.

Comment: Disagree with you including "Henry VIII" in there. If someone calls themselves "Stephen Smith III" that isn't the name written on their birth certificate - it is just appended to their name to distinguish them from their predecessors. If you had a film called "King George V" then that would be the 'name' of that film, but it isn't a sequel to 'King George IV' so misleading to compare it to Terminator 2.

Comment: @Astralbee Nor is "Microsoft Excel 101" referring to the 101st version of "Microsoft Excel", it's part of the name for a different reason, as is the "Indy 500" example in your own answer.

Comment: @Astralbee: A good many people have names that differ from what may be recorded on birth certificates or other official documents.

Comment: That numeric suffix does appear on birth certificates, @Astralbee.  For example, it's on mine.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan that's ridiculous. So is your surname the number and your family name a middle name?

Comment: @jamesqf yeah you're missing the point. If you started calling yourself Susan that doesn't have any bearing on the meaning of '101'. What I said about numbers not being a noun in these examples *is* relevant.

Comment: @Astralbee Not every name consists of exactly one first name, exactly one family name, and zero or more middle names. Calling someone's name "ridiculous" because it doesn't fit the pattern you expect is frankly rather rude. It's perfectly possible that the birth certificate in question makes no such rule, and simply asks for the full name, and that name has been entered with a numeral suffix; or maybe the suffix is common enough in that area that it asks for it in a separate field.

Comment: @IMSoP Indeed, that names fit *no* assumption *at all* is (or should be) database design 101. -- And yet we encounter all these forms that assume a middle initial, assume that the family name is the "last" name, assume that there is a given and a surname at all, that there are common name parts among members of the same family, the the length is limited, that it can be transcribed (let alone in a unique way!) in the latin alphabet, ...

Comment: My objection would be that Terminator 2 is the (common name of the) 2nd movie in the Terminator franchise, Henry VIII is presumably the VIIIth King Henry to bear the name. These are numeric sequences. Math 101 isn't the 101st Math, it's a code shorthand. It's one-oh-one, not one-hundred-and-one, because it's the first course of the first level. The example in IMSoP's answer of the Peugeot 208 is a better analogue (8th model of the 200 series, not the 208th Peugeot).

Answer (score 7):

> Is the number 101 being used as adjective?

No, it's used as a noun.

> shouldn't be come before the noun? like:
>
> 101 Wine

Add the word *"of"* in between the words *"101"* and *"Wine"*. *"101 of Wine"* would essentially mean *"basics of Wine"*.

Comment: to add the word 'of' between 101 and Wine was a genial way to think :)

Comment: @EulerHenriquePintoAraujoVa Sure, just like "500 of Indy" or "43 of bus" or "101.3 of FM".

Comment: @Kaz I'm assuming you're being sarcastic, simply because you wouldn't use it that way. Quite why you addressed your comment at the poor person who's trying to learn English, rather than the person whose answer you are disagreeing with, I don't know.

Comment: @IMSoP In StackExchange comments, if the @ notation is directed at the author of the answer, it is redundant.

Comment: @Kaz That's not what you did though, you addressed it to the person who *asked the question*.

Comment: @IMSoP I see; that is also redundant, I think.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. "101" is a metonym for "introductory course", and wine is a genitive construction that functions as a determiner.

Comment: @IMSoP, Is that possible to use that construction: '101 of wine' I guess it make sense

Comment: @EulerHenriquePintoAraujoVa As you can probably see from the various comments on this page, different people seem to use it differently. Unfortunately, there is no way for someone to tell you which one is "correct" for a colloquial usage like this.

Comment: @IMSoP, I understand your point and I agree tot hat, But is '101 of wine' acceptable english or logically correct?

Comment: @EulerHenriquePintoAraujoVa I can't answer that, for the reason I just gave: some people will think it sounds OK, some will think it sounds wrong. If you want to be safe, just stick to the template "Wine 101", which will be widely understood.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, a dictionary will tell you that '101' is used as an adjective. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/101) states that it signifies "the most basic knowledge about a subject".

Numbers are often adjectives, especially ordinal numbers, and there are different ways of using numbers that can see them placed before, or after the noun. For example "room 2" in a hotel could also be described as "the *second* room". A movie sequel may be called something like '*Titanic 3*', because it is the *third* Titanic movie. The 'Indy 500' is a 500-mile race that takes place in Indiana. So it isn't unusual that we use '101' as a suffix.

Comment: "101 Easy Recipes" is not an example of the pattern the OP is asking about, and in that case "101" doesn't signify "beginner" - you might continue the series with "101 More Recipes" or "101 Expert Recipes". The sequels to "Recipes 101" would instead be "Recipes 102" or "Recipes 201", where the number signifies not the _size_ of the book, but its _difficulty_.

Comment: 101 Easy Recipes means one hundred and one easy recipes. "Easy Recipes 101" is a beginner guide to cooking.

Comment: @IMSoP I didn't say it was an example of it, I stated that is the origin of it. But I've taken it out as it was clearly misleading people who may skim-read.

Comment: @Astralbee It isn't the origin of it, though, and if it was, it wouldn't explain its use as a suffix. See other answers on this page for the real origin.

Comment: @IMSoP So is 'Room 101' the most basic knowledge about a room?

Comment: @Astralbee No, that is yet another coincidental use of the number, from George Orwell's 1984. It is apparently named after a real conference room in BBC Broadcasting House, which in turn was probably "the first room on the first floor". Let's not get into the realms of numerology by trying to connect everything with "101" in it; the examples in the question are clearly referencing the US university usage.

Comment: The US university usage assigns special meaning to "101" after a subject name. But in general, as is pointed out, there are several constructions where number or number-like label modifiers follow a noun, possibly in a name. Other examples are "pages 9-11", "Symphony No. 5", and (with a sequential alphabetic label instead of a number) "Room B". Some linguistic discussion in Section 3.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12928.pdf.

Comment: @IMSoP It's not coincidental. The basic concept of using '101' in *all* situations is that it is one more than 100. In Orwell's novel, it's 'off the scale'. In books, it is marginally better than a book that contains 100 examples. '102' isn't a pleasing number, so releasing a book with '101' of something scuppers the competition because they'd have to come up with at least 49 more until they could have a decent book title.

Comment: @Astralbee That is simply not true. If anything, "Room 101" is a code of the same style as the course codes we're talking about here, but that is not about being "one more than 100", or "more pleasing than 102", it's a coding system where the first digit has a meaning - the first year of university, or the first floor of a building. The codes aren't actually numbers at all - a building with 3 floors of 6 rooms might have "room 306", but clearly doesn't have three hundred rooms. Your recipe example is true, but utterly unrelated to the question.

Comment: Funnily enough, I think the reason Orwell used "Room 101", is precisely the *opposite* of being "off the scale" - it's an utterly normal and boringly bureaucratic name for a room, despite the extraordinary and horrible things that happen there. It's probably one of the most common numbers assigned to rooms throughout the world. It still has nothing to do with introductory courses, though.

Comment: Great answer. It may help to point out that adding a number after a noun that isn't ordinarily numbered is an _idiom_ to refer to a hypothetical but possibly non existent introductory course in a subject about the noun.  The idiom is clearly understood in Australia after being exposed to it by television content from the USA. Hence, by itself "Wine 101" means [something mentioned] would be known by anyone who knows anything about wine.

Comment: IDK about you people but I would prefer not to spend any time in Room 101.

Answer (score 5):

I think the point several other answers are missing is that, in your example, "Wine" is the name of a college course, not the name of something one drinks. "Wine 101" is understood to be an introductory course or information on wine, whereas "Wine 410" is understood to be an advanced course or information on wine. The difference is the number, thus the number is an adjective.

Since the number, 101 or 410, modifies the meaning of the noun, Wine, it'd be an adjective.

If we were talking about bottles of wine in a store, you could probably find brands that use numbers in their name. I recall some Australian wines like this from last time I visited a wine store. In this case the number would be part of a noun.

Whether an adjective should come before or after the noun is flexible.

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, I think this is at best reverse-engineering a possible grammar based on usage of the template. You first have to analyse "wine" as short for "wine course" or "wine tutorial", and can then declare "101" to be an adjective modifying it. I think it's equally possible to say that "101" is short for "101 course" etc, and that wine is modifying that - in which case "101" is functionally a noun. Probably some speakers use it one way and some the other ("that's extremely 101" would be a clear adjective; "the 101 of wine" in another answer is a clear noun), and some neither.

Comment: @IMSoP can we use it with a determiner e.g "the 101", as we do with other nouns? E.g. *the problem*, *an accident*, *no defence*, *some roads*, *few numbers*  etc.  If 101 were a proper noun then it should stand alone without anyone needing to ask "A 101 what?" If it's not a proper noun it should be countable. Asking "How many 101s are there?" will make sense. Does it? You define "101" as a template, I think the terminology is snowclone but the more I reflect  the more I think **adjective is the right answer.**

Comment: @Mari-LouA According to at least one contributor on this page, the answer to your first question is "yes". I think you'd need to spend some time collecting contemporary informal uses before you could reach any conclusion; so far, all the assertions on this page are based on personal experience rather than any such study.

Comment: @IMSoP - language changes organically over time. When universities introduced "course-name number" syntax your point that 'you first have to analyse "wine" as short for "wine course" or "wine tutorial"...' would have applied. Currently, for some time, the meaning of "Wine" in "Wine 101" or "Wine 401" is commonly understood to mean a course on wine. The language has evolved, yes?   Consider Physics courses. Phys 101 is physics but likely Newton's Laws, whereas Phys 610 is still  physics but maybe Quantum Field Theory. The number doesn't really tell us anything except level of complexity.

Comment: @EricM I think you misunderstood me. I'm not saying that noun actually used to be there, or that it's needed for speakers to understand the sentence. I'm saying that if, as a linguist, you wanted to analyse "101" as an adjective, you couldn't say it was modifying "wine", because that would make "wine 101" a type of wine. So, within that linguistic analysis, there is presumably a hidden noun for the adjective to modify, like "course". I don't for one minute think any speaker consciously goes through that analysis, but then we mostly don't consciously think about grammar at all.

Comment: @IMSoP, I am not a linguist, I'm merely looking at it from the common use of the construction Wine 101, or Phys 101 or PolySci 101. Phys 101 is different from Wine 101 obviously because one is about physics and the other wine, but Phys 101 is different from Phys 302 because of area of physics covered. Thus the number modifies the meaning too. But also people at times say Wine 101 to mean "simple", and Wine 302 to mean "sophisticated". The number modifies the meaning I'd say. To your point though, it doesn't have to make it wine the beverage instead of Wine the subject of a class.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I read an article about [illegal baby names in the United States](https://www.usbirthcertificates.com/articles/illegal-baby-names). It is quite curious because there are states in the country where names like: King, Queen, Jesus Christ, III or 1069 are prohibited ...

Now that I have read your query I have thought about whether it would be possible to call a baby: 101 baby, meaning "basics of baby".

Joking aside, I think 101 can be understood both as a noun and as an adjective, since despite being a number, it is also a concrete concept.

In college I had to do math 101 and 102 the first year and math 301 and 302 during the third. These numbers were to aclarate the year and the difficulty of the subject.